# Default Windows Languages?

Tags: windows, default

Is there some default Windows scripting language that comes pre-installed on XP and Vista (Similar to how OS X comes with Python and/or Linux comes with Perl)?

I am aware of Batch scripting but  I am hoping for something a little more robust.  Thanks

**note -** I am on a Linux box so if you guys could give your 2 cents on the Windows scripting languages, it would be appreciated, thanks.

**part deux -** even though ebgreen hates me i accepted his answer because he gave me his 2 cents.

Comment: No hate involved at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows XP and Vista have VBScript and jscript engines installed by default. Windows 7 will also have Powershell installed.

As for my 2 cents, VBScript and jscript are both very mature technologies that have plenty of resources available. Neither of them give you a console if you are looking for that.

Powershell is newer and much much more powerful. It also has the advantage of having a console as well.

Comment: If having a console is a big thing, you can quite easily build one in either VBScript or JScript using stdin and stdout-streams that are available through the WScript object in combination with eval in JScript and Execute/ExecuteGlobal in VBScript.

Comment: That is true, but I don't know why you would want to. It seems to me that installing powershell (or even cygwin with bash) would be easier than writing your own console.

Comment: My only gripe about the PowerShell console is that it *still* doesn't let you easily resize it above a fixed width.

Comment: Really? Mine is 140 columns wide right now. How big are you trying to make it?

Comment: Harper, PowerShell v1 is hosted in the VERY old Windows Console Subsystem, and that means you can't resize, or Ctrl-C to copy, etc. In PowerShell v2 there is a new GUI for PowerShell that is a modern peice of UI.

Comment: I just changed the size of a V1 console window in about 15 seconds. Still not sure exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Scripting Host, invoked through [Cscript.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx) supports VBScript and JScript. [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) is another scripting tool, but it's a separate download.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host for more info on windows script host

Comment: Just for completeness, the WSH can be invoked via WScript.exe as well. As a matter of fact that is the default.

Answer (score 3):

XP and Vista come out of the box with VBScript and JScript support. There's a primer available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98.aspx. Vista can optionally have installed PowerShell which will also ship by default with Windows 7. A powershell primer can be found at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196356.aspx